# Magento Connect Manager > Settings > Deployment Type with SFTP in custom port

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-connect-manager

**Magento v.1.9.2.4**

In Magento Connect Manager > Settings > Deployment Type

Is it possible to use **SFTP** (instead of FTP) in a custom port?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, but I think it is not possible to use Magento Connect with SFTP.

However, you can directly download extensions after you provide the extension key - http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php

Comment: I have tried freegemto to download this http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/Wfs_DisableCompare extension but `failed : cannot get file`.

Comment: to be honest I wouldn't use module for this - regarding this module you can get it from here https://github.com/101senses/magento-Wfs_DisableCompare

Comment: just to add :: this is the first time I see this error on freegento, I'll try to email the developer and find out what is the issue with this module - update will follow